# Requiring some fields to have a data and also to be changed using Validation rule

Tags: picklist, validation-rule, required-field

Scenarios is:
When I changed a certain date field, I want the text field and picklist field to be required and also to be changed? How can I do this using validation rule?

Comment: If you want to change the value of the field automatically, than you can't do that with a validation rule. @Wim's advice would be great. If you just want to check that the user has changed the old value in the text field and the picklist to something new, then i think you can do that with a validation rule. In that case have a look at the function ISCHANGED at https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=0&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a fields value with a validation rule. You could use a Workflow with a field update or use ProcessBuilder to include this logic.